# File IO Printing to screen

Tags: c++, file-io, printing

So my teacher gave us the solutions to a lab we had a couple of weeks ago, and it differs from what I was using when I submitted my assignment. I popped this code into my address book program, but nothing prints out, and I was wondering if anyone knew how to get this to print out to the screen from main. I have tried a few things, but the best I can do is to get one entry to print out and nothing else. Heres the code we were given:

```
void addressBook::showAll2(string fName)
{
 PERSON p;
 PEOPLE2 tp;
 ifstream inData(fName.c_str(), ios::in);
 if(inData.fail())
 throw AddressBookException("Cannot open file to read ");
 people.clear();
 int i = 0;
 while(!inData.eof())
 {
 inData.seekg(i * sizeof(PEOPLE2));
 inData.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&tp), sizeof(PEOPLE2));
 p.fName = tp.fName2;
 p.lName = tp.lName2;
 p.Address = tp.Address2;
 people.push_back(p);
 i++;
 }  
 inData.close();
 return; 
}
```

The only thing I have changed is the throw exception, (our current project). This used to be a bool function, which would return true or false. We were not given the code form main beacuse he isn't concerned with that part, so we rarely ever get it. I'm just wondering if anyone knows how to get this to print out to the screen. I've tried changing it to this:

```
void addressBook::showAll2(string fName, string &str)
{
 PERSON p;
 PEOPLE2 tp;
 ifstream inData(fName.c_str(), ios::in);
 if(inData.fail())
 throw AddressBookException("Cannot open file to read ");
 people.clear();
 int i = 0;
 while(!inData.eof())
 {
 inData.seekg(i * sizeof(PEOPLE2));
 inData.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&tp), sizeof(PEOPLE2));
 p.fName = tp.fName2;
 p.lName = tp.lName2;
 p.Address = tp.Address2;
 people.push_back(p);
 i++;
inData >> str;
 }  
 inData.close();
 return; 
}
```

and in main I have this:

```
void printFile()  //prints stored file info to screen
 {  
 string str;
 addressBook *newBook = addressBook::newbookInst();
 Menu *m = Menu::menuInst();
 try
 {
 newBook->showAll2("addressbook", str);

 cout << str << '/n' << endl;
 }
    catch(exception e)
{
    cerr << e.what();
}
 m->waitKey();
 }
```

So does anyone care to show me what I am missing? The assignment is already done, so feel free to explain it in detail if you'd like, or just post code and I can figure it out. I'm going a little crazy trying to understand how I get this to print with this code. (My version worked just fine btw, but doesn't do any of this.) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your professors code is wrong because it tests eof in the wrong place, it also does a needless seekg, I'd be worried that your professor is writing bad code.

```
while(!inData.eof())
{
    inData.seekg(i * sizeof(PEOPLE2));
    inData.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&tp), sizeof(PEOPLE2));
    ...
}
```

should be written like this

```
for (;;)
{
    inData.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&tp), sizeof(PEOPLE2));
    if (inDate.eof())
        break;
    ...
}
```

You should test for eof *after* you read not *before*. It's a very common mistake among newbies, but it's not a mistake your professor should be making. Secondly there's no need for seekg, since you are just going through the file from beginning to end. It's not a bug, but it's not necessary.

`inData.close` is also unnecessary because the ifstream destructor will close the file for you.

Answer to your question simply is this

```
inData.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&tp), sizeof(PEOPLE2));
p.fName = tp.fName2;
p.lName = tp.lName2;
p.Address = tp.Address2;
cout << p.fName << ' ' << p.lName << ' ' << pAddress << '\n';
```

Try that code with you professor's version of the loop and you'll probably see why it's bugged.

Comment: So I should put all of that in main? He is a stickler for using cout in our functions, says its bad practice. I've never understood why, but mine is not to question, simply to do. AS for the seekg, I was a little confused as to why it was in there myself, but when I asked about this, he said that it works on his computer, and left it at that. I think thats because he's not a fan of people whining about grades and how stuff is done on homework, (they do tend to complain a lot, but mostly because they are too lazy to do the work). Regardless, I'll give this a go, thanks!

Comment: Here's a question, how does this print from the file? Doesn't this just print from what's stored in the address book, regardless of whats in the file?

Comment: ''Not using cout in functions' That's good advice. The reason is that it makes the functions less flexible. What you should do depends on your goal. If you want cleaner code without cout in your function, then just write out the people vector that is being built up.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding what you are asking. How is what's in the address book different from what's in the file? The code above prints out what's in the file as far as I can tell.

Comment: So I tried this, and it prints the two permanent names I have stored for testing, and then repeats the last one. Then, if it do a normal printout, it adds that extra repeat into the stored names, and then when I print the file out with this code again, its adds yet another repeated entry. This just continues on and on, adding the same entry over and over. That's just weird

Comment: That's the bug I was talking about. change your professors loop to my loop, and that problem should go away.

Comment: Well, yeah, as the program is right now, the file just saves whatever is currently in the address book. But, I can go into the file and add another name manually, and should be able to print it out with the new entry. this is what I did... `void addressBook::showAll2()
{ 
 ifstream indata("addressbook.dat", ios::binary);
 string file;

 if(indata.is_open())
 {
  while(indata >> file)
  {
   cout << file << "\n" << endl;
  }
 }
 else
 {
  cout << "Sorry, file did not open for reading " << endl;
 }
 indata.close();
}` and that woks just fine, (although he didn't like it)

Comment: I'm going to play around with this tomorrow, and try to see if I can figure out how to make it work. I have to submit the error catching stuff tonight though, so for now I'm going with this: `void addressBook::showAll2(string fName, string &str)
{ 
 ifstream indata(fName.c_str(), ios::binary);

 if(indata.is_open())
 {
 indata >> str;
 }
 else
 {
  throw AddressBookException("Could not open file to print ");
 }
 indata.close();
}` because it works and I can test my exception on it. Thanks for the help though!